# split ArrayList and make statistics using java 8 Stream

Tags: java, filter, java-8, statistics, java-stream

I have ArraList of following objects:

```
public class Point {
    private double[] position; // hold x y z coordinate
    private double[] velocity; // hold velocity vector
    private double value; // some value
    /*
     * setters, geters another calculations ...
     */
}
```

I need to split those points into let's say 10 areas base on Point.position[0]. At each area I want to calculate avegage velocity and find out min / max of position[2].

So how wide is the subarea:

```
body = new ArrayList<>(); // array of points, filled from file

DoubleSummaryStatistics ds = body.parallelStream().mapToDouble(Point::x).summaryStatistics();
step = (ds.getMax() - ds.getMin()) / 10; // let's say I want 10 subareas

from = ds.getMin();
to = from + krok;
```

my idea is go in loop and filter points and make statistics

```
List<Point> subArea;
for (int i = 0; i < kolkoUsekov; i++) {
    subArea = body.parallelStream().filter(b -> from<=b.y && b.y<to).collect(Collectors.toList());

    // do statistics
    // #1 
    subArea.forEach(...);

    // or #2
    DoubleSummaryStatistics ds =  subArea.parallelStream().mapToDouble(Point::z).summaryStatistics();
    ds = subArea.parallelStream().mapToDouble(Point::velocityX).summaryStatistics();
    ds = subArea.parallelStream().mapToDouble(Point::velocityY).summaryStatistics();
    ds = subArea.parallelStream().mapToDouble(Point::velocityZ).summaryStatistics();
    /* ... */

    // print statistics

    from += krok;
    to += krok;
}
```

PROBLEM:
- in lambda I have to have final and my variables FROM, TO are not
- I will loop 4 times over subarea to find complete statistics in option #2

thank you very much to help me with filtering and finding some good idea for fast statistics

Answer (score 0):

I did find this helpfull http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/architect-streams-pt2-2227132.html

so I did create new method in Point Object

```
public Integer whichPart(double min, double step, int axe) {
    return new Integer((int) ((position[axe] - min) / step));
}
```

later, prepare some data

```
ds = body.parallelStream().mapToDouble(Bod::y).summaryStatistics();
min = ds.getMin();
step = (ds.getMax() - min) / 12; // I want 12 subareas
```

and then grouping

```
Map<Integer, List<Bod>> rozdeleneBody = body.parallelStream()
           .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(b->b.whichPart(min,step,1)));
```

now maybe I will loop over grouped list or I will create custom collector

Comment: There is no need for `new Integer(…)`. And double brackets have no advantage over single brackets…